# Postgresql Add WHERE clauses in an UPDATE request

Tags: sql, postgresql

I intend to write a SQL request UPDATE and I'd like to verify if table2.fld5 already contains 'Hello' in order to not write it several times, but didn't find a way to achieve this verification.

The request is :

```
UPDATE table2
    SET fld5 = concat(fld5, 'Hello')
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM table1
                      WHERE table1.fld1 = table2.fld1 AND
                            table1.fld2 = table2.fld2 AND
                            table1.fld3 = table2.fld3
                     )
     AND table2.fld4 > (NOW() - INTERVAL '79 MINUTE');
```

Comment: Note that this is not concurrency-safe. Unless you have locks on the table you're modifying (and all the tables you're joining on) to stop people deleting or inserting rows, a concurrent xact could insert hello even as you determine that it doesn't exist and decide to insert it. For a correct way to handle problems like this look into `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT UPDATE ...`

Answer (score 1):

How about adding the condition to the `where`:

```
UPDATE table2
    SET fld5 = concat(fld5, 'Hello')
    WHERE (fld5 not like '%Hello' OR fld5 IS NULL) AND  -- perhaps this should be '%Hello%'
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM table1
                      WHERE table1.fld1 = table2.fld1 AND
                            table1.fld2 = table2.fld2 AND
                            table1.fld3 = table2.fld3 AND
                            table2.fld4 > (NOW() - INTERVAL '79 MINUTE')
                     );
```

I agree with the comment about the `fld4` comparison.  I think this is the logic:

```
UPDATE table2
    SET fld5 = concat(fld5, 'Hello')
    WHERE (table2.fld5 not like '%Hello' OR table2.fld5 IS NULL) AND  -- perhaps this should be '%Hello%' AND
          table2.fld4 > (NOW() - INTERVAL '79 MINUTE') AND  -- or should this be <
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM table1
                      WHERE table1.fld1 = table2.fld1 AND
                            table1.fld2 = table2.fld2 AND
                            table1.fld3 = table2.fld3                                
                     );
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, however the NOT LIKE doesn't seem to work because the request updates 0 line.

Comment: IMO the `table2.fld4 > (NOW() - INTERVAL '79 MINUTE')` should be in the main query, not in the `not exists()` subquery.

Comment: @Sovakah . . . Perhaps the issue is `NULL` values.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your date check needs to be outside of the exists subquery:

```
UPDATE table2 SET fld5 = concat(fld5, 'Hello') 
WHERE fld5 NOT LIKE '%Hello%' AND table2.fld4 > (NOW() - INTERVAL '79 MINUTE'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.fld1 = table2.fld1 AND table1.fld2 = table2.fld2 AND table1.fld3 = table2.fld3))
```

;